# How to handle an array of arrays in MediatR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cqrs, mediatr

I have a command

```
public class UpdateEntityCommand: IRequest<bool>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OtherEntityDto> Instruments{ get; set; }
}
```

I need to update many entities in one request. Can I do something like this or there are a better way?

```
public class UpdateEntitiesCommand: IRequest<bool>
{
    public IEnumerable<UpdateEntityCommand> Commands { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing your OtherEntityDto is something like this:

```
class OtherEntityDto 
{
   public Guid Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

How I would do it is to have a command such as:

```
public class UpdateInstrumentsCommand: IRequest<bool>
{
   public IEnumerable<OtherEntityDto> UpdatedInstrumemnts {get;set}
}
```

and then, in the command handler I will match the persisted entities with what's in the `UpdatedInstrumemnts` based on the `Id` property and update their name accordingly. I hope this makes sense to you